# Comparing Permutation and Combinations

Tags: python, compare, combinations, permutation

I have big list with all possible combinations

```
items = ["Apple","Banana","Orange","Peach"]
combs = []
for c in combinations(items, 2)):
    combs.append([c[0],c[1]])
```

Which gives:

```
[['Apple', 'Banana'], ['Apple', 'Orange'], ['Apple', 'Peach'], ['Banana', 'Orange'], ['Banana', 'Peach'], ['Orange', 'Peach']]
```

And the user may input two items from that list,

I want to get the Index of the said combination in the list.

I can do that If the user input in the right order, like "Apple Banana", but not if it's the opposite "Banana Apple". Because there's no ["Banana", "Apple"]

I know I can use permutations in the input so it gives both ["Banana", "Apple"] and the correct one ['Apple', 'Banana']. But how do I check if one is in the other without using nested for-loops? Even this small check leads to 12 iterations.

Here's the nest loop:

```
for pr in permutations([input1, input2], 2):
    for comb in combinations(items, 2):
        if ..........:
            dosomething
```

Comment: How about using `set` to store the combinations?

Comment: Martijn's got the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to build all the combinations; what you are looking for are [set operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
items = set(["Apple","Banana","Orange","Peach"])
if {input1, input2} <= items:
    # valid subset
```

Demo:

```
>>> items = set(["Apple","Banana","Orange","Peach"])
>>> {'Apple', 'Banana'} <= items
True
>>> {'Banana', 'Apple'} <= items
True
>>> {'Banana', 'Watermelon'} <= items
False
```

If you wanted the index of the combination, then you create *sets* with the combination too:

```
inputs = {input1, input2}
found = None
for i, combo in enumerate(combinations(items, 2)):
    if set(combo) == inputs:
        found = i
        break
```

or, as a generator expression:

```
inputs = {input1, input2}
found = next((i for i, c in enumerate(combinations(items, 2))
                if set(c) == inputs), None)
```

Demo:

```
>>> items = ["Apple","Banana","Orange","Peach"]
>>> inputs = {'Banana', 'Apple'}
>>> next((i for i, c in enumerate(combinations(items, 2)) if set(c) == inputs), None)
0
```

Comment: Well, even tho I didn't knew about this, it is not what I was looking for, I need to get the Index of the combination.